# "decodeURIComponent" items in JSON List

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse all the items in the JSON list and using the function decode, remove the HTML formatted spaces, %20 and the like.

See snippet below

My goals:

- I want to change Andy%2EPeters to "Andy Peters"
- I dont want to have to refer to each item as "this.**product_model**" using the key name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(ray).each(function(index) {
      console.log("Item BEFORE Decode : " + index + ": " + $(this).text() + ": " + this.product_model);
      this.index = decodeString(this.item);
      console.log("Item AFTER Decode    : " + index + ": " + $(this).text() + ": " + this.product_model);
    });
  });
});

function decodeString(a) {
  if (typeof a != 'undefined') {
    return decodeURIComponent(a);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
var ray = [{
  "product_id": "1",
  "product_model": "Andy%2EPeters",
}, {
  "product_id": "2",
  "product_model": "Tom%2EHanks",
}, {
  "product_id": "1",
  "product_model": "HFJ5G1.5",
}, ];



//console setup 
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
  log: function(text) {
    $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
  }
};
```

```css
.console-line {
  font-family: console;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn" value="Go!">
<div id="console-log"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: ...that will yield `this[0]`, `this[1]`...what's the point? You're in an `each` loop. So `this` is one item.

Comment: Why not `data = decodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify([your data object]))` and then do `JSON.parse(data)` This will decode all the data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
         var data = decodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(ray).replace(/(%2E)/ig, "%20"));
         ray = JSON.parse(data);
    
         $(ray).each(function(){
            console.log(this.product_model);
         })
  });
});
var ray = [{
  "product_id": "1",
  "product_model": "Andy%2EPeters"
}, {
  "product_id": "2",
  "product_model": "Tom%2EHanks"
}, {
  "product_id": "1",
  "product_model": "HFJ5G1.5"
} ];

//console setup 
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
  log: function(text) {
    $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
  }
};
```

```css
.console-line {
  font-family: console;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn" value="Go!">
<div id="console-log"></div>
```

This uses the JSON object's native `stringify` to parse the object to a JSON string. Before decoding is done replace all the `%2E` with `%20` and finally decode it all together. Then parse it back to a JavaScript object.

> I don't know if this is for demonstration purposes only, but generally speaking: overwriting the console is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Mouser, solved! Also, the console was purely for demo on JSFiddle/CodeSnippet.

Comment: @platinums - just an fyi, the extra commas in your `ray` array breaks in IE8 and older.

Comment: @wahwahwah, didn't see those. Thanks for mentioning, updated my solution.

Comment: Mouser also, please explain why you "replace all the %2E with %20"

Comment: @platinums Human readability - `%2E` is a dot and `%20` a white space.